# Problems downloading the packages xserver-xephyr

Tags: installation, software-center, package-management, synaptic

I tried various things to download `xserver-xephyr` package, all I got was various error messages.

They are as follows:

- First through Ubuntu Software Center

[image: this is what USC offered me]

- Then I tried the command:

  `sudo apt-get install xserver-xephyr --fix-missing`

[image: this is terminal's gift]

- Then i tried downloading the .deb via Firefox and installing it through gdebi.
  [image]
- I also tried synaptic, which fails.

  ---

> so what shuold i do now?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it.
another package, `xserver-common` was required to install this one.
It works perfectly now.

BTW I needed this one to install **Ubuntu Builder**